# Assigning function to a variable in python, two different ways

Tags: python, function

I was taking a python training from udemy and suddenly found out that in python, we can assign a function to a variable and as I was practising, I found out that there are two ways it can be done. For example, suppose we are defining a function `hello()` as bellow:

```
def hello(name="Neel"):
    return "hello "+name
```

Now consider the two assignment:
`greet = hello`
and 
`greet = hello()`

So I want to know what are the differences between them and how's the picture behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

`greet = hello` gives you a function object. When you `print(greet)` you will get something like `<function object....>`. This is because you are assigning the function `hello` to the variable named `greet`.

`greet = hello()` on the other hand is assigning the return value of the `hello` function to the variable `greet`. Since your default argument for `name` in the function `hello()` is `Neel`, thus `greet = hello()` essentially would result in `print(greet)` giving you `hello Neel` which is a string (and not a function object.

Hope this answers your question!